# ( Python ) Can you swap the starting process of the selection sort?

Tags: python, selection-sort

from finding the minimun and put it on the left to finding the maximum and put it on the right

```
def SelectionSort(a_list):
    n = len(a_list)

    for i in range(0, n-1):
        iMin = i
        print(a_list)

        for j in range(i+1, n):
            if a_list[j] < a_list[iMin]:
                iMin = j

        temp = a_list[i]
        a_list[i] = a_list[iMin]
        a_list[iMin] = temp
    
    print()
    return a_list

someList = [45,984,6,90,8946,89]
SelectionSort(someList)
```

Can it swap the process from minimum => maximum to minimum <= maximum

the answer should look like this.

[6, 45, 89, 89, 984, 8946]

Comment: Just change `<` to `>`?

Comment: By the way, you can replace the swap with `a_list[i], a_list[iMin] = a_list[iMin], a_list[i]`.

Comment: I tried that but it reverse the answer I wanted that the answer should look like it normally sorted from minimum to the maximum

Comment: Oh, I thought you were asking how to sort in decreasing order.

Comment: I know it sound confusing because I was confused too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes:

- Rename `iMin` to `iMax`
- Mirror the two ranges you use:

  - `range(0, n-1)` becomes `range(n-1, 0, -1)`
  - `range(i+1, n)` becomes `range(i-1, -1, -1)`
- Mirror the comparison operator

  - `<` becomes `>`

Result:

```
def SelectionSort(a_list):
    n = len(a_list)

    for i in range(n-1, 0, -1):
        iMax = i
        print(a_list)

        for j in range(i-1, -1, -1):
            if a_list[j] > a_list[iMax]:
                iMax = j

        temp = a_list[i]
        a_list[i] = a_list[iMax]
        a_list[iMax] = temp
    
    print()
    return a_list
```

Unrelated to your question (and as commented), swapping can be done like this:

```
    a_list[i], a_list[iMax] = a_list[iMax], a_list[i]
```